# Establishing communication between Java client and .NET server

Tags: java, .net, remoting, interop

I would like to create a server using .NET and Java client (Android application).

The client will be connected to the server through mobile network so it's impossible to use tcp socket for two-way communication.

I would like to develop a logic for client login:

The client sends username and password to the server and server replies (connected/not connected). Then if client is connected it starts sending data stream using tcp sockets.

So far I have looked at some of the tutorials for Java/.Net interoperability and remoting but still haven't found the solution for login logic described above.

I would really appreciate any suggestion on how to create a logic for login or any good tutorial recommendation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not having ever coded against Android I don't really know it's limitations.  However, I'd say your best bet is probably going to be using HTTP communication through soapy or restful webservices.

I'd recommend looking into WCF for your .Net server side components.  This will allow you to deploy either a Soap connector or a Rest connector or both.  Then you will likely be able to use standard HTTP basic authentication for your login logic.

With a Soap or Rest based service, you'll be able to use any of the numerous soap libraries for Java or you can do all of the HTTP stuff manually using Java's built in libraries.